# How to disable ipv6 on a specific interface in Linux?

Tags: linux, networking, centos, script, ipv6

Could someone tell me how to disable ipv6 auto-config on a specific network interface in CentOS?

The current situation is:

A PC has two network adapters eth0 and eth1 that are connecting to the same LAN, in which, IPv6 router is advertising an IPv6 prefix with NDRA (Neighbor Discovery Router Advertisements) packet. As a result, both eth0 and eth1 are configuring the IPv6 address with that prefix automatically.

But, I just want to enable ipv6 on eth1 and disable it on eth0. I've tried the following methods, but they don't work.

#### 1. /etc/sysconfig/network

```
NETWORKING_IPV6=no
IPV6_AUTOCONF=no
```

This will disable ipv6 on both eth0 and eth1.

#### 2. /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0

```
IPV6INIT=no
IPV6_AUTOCONF=no
```

Then, it doesn't work. I have restarted the network service already.

Comment: sysconfig.txt definitely implies that what you've done should disable IPv6 on a specific interface. However, it seems those flags are ignored. There are two bug reports about this, which were also ignored. See https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=982740 & https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=496444

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You can disable it from /etc/sysctl.conf with this line:

```
net.ipv6.conf.eth0.disable_ipv6 = 1
```

Take a look at /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/eth0. There are many options you can set in that directory, like leaving IPv6 enabled but disabling autoconf etc.

Comment: FYI for those looking to disable all, not just one interface, simply replace "eth0" with "all"

Comment: Actually, instead of modifying `/etc/sysctl.conf`, create a file in `/etc/sysctl.d` named for example `00_ipv6_off.conf` with the above contents. `ifconfig` will then show interfaces bereft of IPv6 functionality.

Comment: In one line: `echo "net.ipv6.conf.eth0.disable_ipv6 = 1" > /etc/sysctl.d/00_ipv6_off.conf`

Comment: While the `sysctl` command works for me, adding the file in `sysctl.d` does not work. When the system reboots, `net.ipv6.conf.ens32.disable_ipv6` is still 0 when running the `sysctl` command to check. I am on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

Answer (score 17):

Let the interface name be stored in the `iface` variable (must be adapted to your situation) :

```
$ iface=eth0
```

Then the command is :

```
$ sudo sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.$iface.disable_ipv6=1
```

deprecates

```
# echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/$iface/disable_ipv6
```

In order to ensure that this change persists across reboots, you'll want to add this line to your `/etc/sysctl.conf` file:

```
net.ipv6.conf.$iface.disable_ipv6=1
```

To check if the change was kept (especially after reboot) :

```
$ sysctl -n net.ipv6.conf.$iface.disable_ipv6
1
```

Answer (score 9):

One way to temporally remove the ipv6 on an interface is: (it will come back after reboot)

`ip -6 addr flush eth0`

Comment: This is great for me, I had one host (the proxmox apt repo) that was slow on ipv6 so just needed it gone for one session. Thanks!

Comment: Had the same problem as @trisweb, and this worked great thanks a ton lepe

Answer (score 4):

You should be root to set network parameter below:

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/wlan0/disable_ipv6
```

Comment: This will work in installers as well, if a debian installer is getting stuck at detect network settings. Go to console (alt+2), and type this command. Go back to the installer. Press Ctrl+C to exit the detection, and re-initialize the detection of the network.

Answer (score 3):

The use of the following variables in ifcfg-eth0 or ifcfg-eth1:

```
IPV6INIT=no
IPV6_AUTOCONF=no
```

Should do the trick. To reiterate:

#### /etc/sysconfig/network

```
NETWORKING_IPV6=yes
IPV6_AUTOCONF=yes
```

#### /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0

```
IPV6INIT=no
IPV6_AUTOCONF=no
```

#### /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0

```
IPV6INIT=yes
IPV6_AUTOCONF=yes
```

Then make sure you restart the networking service:

```
% /etc/init.d/network restart
```

If you run `ifconfig` you should see inet6 on the ethernet device (either eth0 or eth1) that has ipv6 enabled.

```
% ifconfig eth0
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 01:26:BD:85:CA:30  
          inet addr:192.168.1.20  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::226:c7ff:fe85:a720/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:2497072 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2253781 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:2004576667 (1.8 GiB)  TX bytes:1296051472 (1.2 GiB)
```

Comment: Yes, it's a little weird. Setting "net.ipv6.conf.eth0.disable_ipv6 = 1 " is a good solution. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Hmmmm, didn't do squat on my system (RH 6.5 X86_64 on a virtualized environment.) Good to know those for those systems where it works, though.

Answer (score 0):

sudo vi /etc/modprobe.d/ipv6.conf

```
# add following line 
options ipv6 disable=1
```

sudo reboot