# Is IPV6 blocking my DHCP on Fedora?

Tags: fedora, dhcp, ipv6

I’m running Fedora 20 with KDE on a laptop I use for work.  When I’m at home I use DHCP and when at work I have to statically assign an IP.  When I came home the other day for some reason it doesn’t get an IP.  Changed cables, other computers in my home network are working fine.

In the KDE network manager I usually change the setting.  For the interface enp0s25, IPv4 is required and IPv6 is ignored.

So I started messing in the command line.

```
[user@F20 ~]$ ifconfig
 enp0s25: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet6 fe80::2ad2:44ff:fe31:fece  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether 28:d2:44:31:fe:ce  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 20  bytes 4832 (4.7 KiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
    device interrupt 20  memory 0xf1600000-f1620000

[user@F20 ~]$ cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-enp0s25 
TYPE="Ethernet"
BOOTPROTO=dhcp
DEFROUTE="yes"
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=yes
IPV6INIT=no
IPV6_AUTOCONF="no"
IPV6_DEFROUTE="yes"
IPV6_FAILURE_FATAL="no"
NAME="enp0s25"
UUID="b32402c2-05f3-4dd5-bd46-2edf21f3358a"
ONBOOT="yes"
IPV6_PEERDNS=yes
IPV6_PEERROUTES=yes
HWADDR=28:D2:44:31:FE:CE
PEERDNS=yes
PEERROUTES=yes
```

This page:
[How to disable ipv6 on a specific interface in linux?](https://superuser.com/questions/575684/how-to-disable-ipv6-on-a-specific-interface-in-linux)

Suggests that I make these changes.

```
[user@F20 ~]$ cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-enp0s25 
IPV6_AUTOCONF="no"
IPV6_DEFROUTE="no"
```

So I do that:

```
[user@F20 ~]$ sudo /etc/init.d/network restart
Restarting network (via systemctl):  Job for network.service failed. See 'systemctl status network.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.
                                                       [FAILED]


[user@F20 ~]$ journalctl -a | grep failed

Aug 07 14:31:25 F20 systemd[1]: Unit network.service entered failed state.
Aug 07 14:32:13 F20 NetworkManager[975]: <info> (enp0s25): device state change: ip-config -> failed                 (reason 'ip-config-unavailable') [70 120 5]
Aug 07 14:32:13 F20 NetworkManager[975]: <warn> Activation (enp0s25) failed for connection 'enp0s25'
Aug 07 14:32:13 F20 NetworkManager[975]: <info> (enp0s25): device state change:failed -> disconnected (reason 'none') [120 30 0]

[sudo] password for user: 
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl restart  NetworkManager.service
```

So I try this:

```
[user@F20 ~]$ cat /etc/sysctl.conf
# System default settings live in /usr/lib/sysctl.d/00-system.conf.
# To override those settings, enter new settings here, or in an /etc/sysctl.d/<name>.conf file
#
# For more information, see sysctl.conf(5) and sysctl.d(5).

net.ipv6.conf.enp0s25.disable_ipv6 = 1
```

And it removes the IPv6, but still doesn’t give me an IPv4 DHCP address.

```
[user@F20 ~]$
enp0s25: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    ether 28:d2:44:31:fe:ce  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 25  bytes 8650 (8.4 KiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
    device interrupt 20  memory 0xf1600000-f1620000  

wlp4s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 192.168.1.162  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
    inet6 fe80::5e51:4fff:fe54:4589  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether 5c:51:4f:54:45:89  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 151  bytes 19996 (19.5 KiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 137  bytes 20501 (20.0 KiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

What am I overlooking?

Comment: Please not this is just for the enp0s25 wired interface, the wlp4s0 wireless interface is working fine.

Comment: IPv4 and IPv6 are separate protocols. IPv6 settings should have no influence on IPv4.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to have been a bug.  Update fixed the issue.