# How to remove only one IPv6 address from an interface?

Tags: networking, ipv6

I have board with `linux kernel 2.6.23.12` where on `eth0` interface it has two IPv6 addresses.

```
root@ramana:~# ifconfig eth0
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr FF:AB:CD:EF:85:94  
          inet addr:192.168.20.107  Bcast:192.168.20.255 Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::20d:b9ff:fe3c:8594/64 Scope:Link
          inet6 addr: 2001:1890:110e:1111::a245/64 Scope:Global
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:6289 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:12197 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:587799 (574.0 KiB)  TX bytes:2057305 (1.9 MiB)
          Interrupt:10 Base address:0x4000
```

I want to disable the first ipv6 address in this. How do I do that?

Well there's a question [here](https://superuser.com/questions/575684/how-to-disable-ipv6-on-a-specific-interface-in-linux). But there are no such files in my kernel.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable ipv6 on a specific interface in linux?](http://superuser.com/questions/575684/how-to-disable-ipv6-on-a-specific-interface-in-linux)

Comment: the question is why you want to disable link local IPv6 ? you might whish to use a random base instead of mac base adress, but that's another question. You global IP is not giving your mac addess, that a good point.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Generally, you *really should not* remove the link-local address, as it is required for core IPv6 features to work, such as Neighbour Discovery (i.e. IPv6 ARP).

That said, you can use `ip addr` to add or delete IPv4/6 addresses:

```
ip addr del 2001:1890:110e:1111::a245/64 dev eth0
```

`ip` is the modern Linux network configuration tool, and `ifconfig` should be avoided on Linux. It still can delete individual addresses, but only for IPv6:

```
ifconfig eth0 del 2001:1890:110e:1111::a245/64
```

Comment: +1 for not removing it. It will give you more trouble than you think.

Answer (score 4):

That first IPv6 address is the link-local address. Every IPv6 interface must have one. It's perfectly normal for an interface to have multiple IPv6 addresses.

Answer (score 1):

To remove IPv6 addresses from the interface you need to specify "-6" parameter for "ip" command like this:

```
$ sudo ip -6 addr del fe80::20d:b9ff:fe3c:8594/64 dev eth0
```

without it the command is executing successfully, but no changes to the interface.

Answer (score -4):

1. Enter Interface Configuration mode for the VLAN 1 interface.
   SEFOS# configure terminal
   SEFOS(config)# interface vlan 1
2. Delete the IPv6 address configured for that interface.
   SEFOS(config-if)# no ipv6 address fec0::1111:0:1 96
   SEFOS(config-if)# no ipv6 address fe80::203:2ff:fe03:501 link-local
   SEFOS(config-if)# exit
   SEFOS(config)# exit
3. Review the IPv6 information for the VLAN 1 interface.
   SEFOS# show ipv6 interface vlan 1

vlan1 is up, line protocol is up
    IPv6 is Enabled
    Link local address:
        fe80::214:4fff:fe6c:560f
...
The link-local address is auto-configured when you remove a link-local address in the IPv6 interface.
Or click on the link below for more information
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E39109_01/html/E24662/z40000f71393620.html

Comment: That's nice, but the question is about Linux, not IOS or SEFOS, and if you just [copy-paste from the first Google result](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19285-01/html/E24662/z40000f71393443.html), you really should mention that.

Comment: Yeah, that was why i inserted the link i got it from